# Assign and compare in python

Tags: python, regex, match

I need to do re.match sequentially, and in match case I need result of match to optain groups. Now I can do next:

```
r = re.match('cond1', l)
if r:
    # work with r.group()
else:
    r = re.match('cond2', l)
    if r:
        # work with r.group()
    else:
        r = re.match('cond3', l)
        if r:
            # work with r.group()
```

etc. But how can I do better? I see it is not possible to perform assignment in if like this:

```
if r = re.match('cond1', l):
    # work with r.group()
elif r = re.match('cond2', l):
    # work with r.group()
elif r = re.match('cond3', l)
    # work with r.group()
```

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I realized it, but how to deal with such problem better?

Comment: Normally, when you're trying to chain 3 or more things together, it's better to ask how to chain any arbitrary number of things together. Which usually means a loop (or an implicit loop, e.g., in a call to `map`, or a recursive function).

Comment: Also, if you're literally matching these three patterns, why not just `r = re.match('cond[123]', l)`?

Comment: Your cascading ifs are fine (functional, intelligable, normal, and easy to understand in six months when you come back to this code to fix a bug.. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a comprehension:

```
r, cond = next((m,c) for (m,c) in ((re.match(cond, line), cond) for cond in ('cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3')) if m)

if cond=='cond1':
    # work with r.group() for cond1
elif cond=='cond2':
    # work with r.group() for cond2
```

Or if that looks too arcane, a loop:

```
for cond in ('cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3'):
    r = re.match(cond, line)
    if r:
        break

if not r:
    # no match
elif cond=='cond1':
    # work with r.group() for cond1
elif cond=='cond2':
    # work with r.group() for cond2
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it often helps to refactor things out into functions. In this case, it helps because you can easily return early from a function; you can't return early from a block of code in the middle of other code.

```
def first_match(haystack):
    r = re.match('cond1', haystack)
    if r:
        # work with r.group()
        return
    r = re.match('cond2', l)
    if r:
        # work with r.group()
        return
    r = re.match('cond3', l)
    if r:
        # work with r.group()
```

All the `else` bits and indentation headaches go away.

---

Also, in general, when you're asking how to chain 3 or more things together, the right answer is to figure out how to chain any arbitrary number of things together, and just do that with N=3. Which usually means a loop (or a loop hidden inside a function like `map`, or a recursive function definition, etc.). For example:

```
def first_match(exprs, haystack):
    for expr in exprs:
        r = re.match(expr, haystack)
        if r:
            return r
```

---

In this case, however, what you're trying to do is actually doable. Maybe not a good idea, but… A regex `match` object is always truthy. And of course `None` is falsey. So:

```
r = re.match('cond1', l) or re.match('cond2', l) or re.match('cond3', l)
if r:
    # work with r.group(), which is the group for whichever matched
```

But notice that if you want to use the truthiness, you can do that in a loop too:

```
next(filter(bool, (re.match(cond, l) for cond in ('cond1', 'cond2', 'cond3'))))
```

---

Finally, you're already using regular expressions, so why not use regular expressions?

```
r = re.match('cond[123]', l)
if r:
    # work with r.group()
```